# Subfield of a number field with one complex place is totally real

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

My memory of field theory is very hazy, so this may be quite simple. The exercise certainly sounds simple:

> Let $K$ be a number field with exactly one complex place. Show that every proper subfield of $K$ is totally real.

In the text I'm reading, real and complex places are defined as follows: all finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ (i.e. number fields) are simple, so $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. If the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ splits as $(x-\alpha_1)\dotsb(x-\alpha_n)$ for $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{C}$, then the number of real places of $K$ is the number of $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{R}$, and the number of complex places is half the number of $\alpha_i \notin \mathbb{R}$ (half, since these will occur in complex conjugate pairs). I know there's some other definition in terms of valuations, but I'm not familiar with that at the moment.

I'm really not sure how to approach this at all. I've played with some examples in Mathematica, but I'm not seeing any sort of pattern between the number of real and complex places of $K$ and a subfield thereof.

Comment: Having one complex place means there are only two field embeddings $K \to \mathbf C$ with image not in $\mathbf R$.  Suppose a subfield $F$ with $n = [K:F] \geq 2$ has a field embedding to $\mathbf C$ with image not in $\mathbf R$.  How many extensions are there of a field embedding $F \to \mathbf C$ to a field embedding $K \to \mathbf C$?

Comment: I thought I had read somewhere that there was only one, which was what confused me. But I suppose it must be $[K:F]$ for all of this to make sense. Does it then also follow that each of the embeddings of $K$ is distinct? E.g. if $F$ has 2 complex embeddings and $[K:F]=3$, are there then 6 distinct complex embeddings of $K$?

Comment: Yes, the number of embeddings of the larger field is the field degree $[K:F]$. Think of it this way: you can always write $K = F(\beta)$ for some $\beta$, so starting from a field embedding $F \hookrightarrow \mathbf C$ you just need to figure out where $\beta$ could go, and there will be $[K:F]$ choices for that.  An extension to $K$ of a complex (= nonreal) embedding of $F$ must be a complex embedding, while the extensions to $K$ of a real embedding of $F$ may be real or may be complex.